# Can't render from array map on const

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to create a const component to render a select with its options, but I can't render option fields because the code returns a select with no one options. Where's the problem?

Thank you in advice.

```js
import React from "react";

const FilterSelect = (props) => {
    const {title, name, selectedValue, optionsValue, onChange} = {...props};

    const renderOptions = (optionsValue) => {
        optionsValue.map((optionValue, i) =>
            <option value={optionValue.value} key={i}>{optionValue.name}</option>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className="filters-content-block">
            <h3 className="filters-subtitle">{title}</h3>
            <select className="sl sl-fullwidth" onChange={onChange} required>
                {renderOptions}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FilterSelect;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `renderOptions` is a function. You either have to call it passing `optionsValue` as a parameter; or change the code so that `renderOptions` is no longer a function but an array, like so:

```
const renderOptions = optionsValue.map((optionValue, i) =>
    <option value={optionValue.value} key={i}>{optionValue.name}</option>
    );
```

Comment: In my opinion this is the best solution, so I change my code using it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You defined `renderOptions` as a method but forgot to sent `optionsValue` to it.

```
<select className="sl sl-fullwidth" onChange={onChange} required>
  {renderOptions(optionsValue)}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You renderOptions is a function. So you must call it like so:

```
<select className="sl sl-fullwidth" onChange={onChange} required>
  {renderOptions()}
</select>
```

You can get rid of the optionsValue param because you have it from props. and you must return from the function. Try considering this:

```
const renderOptions = () => {
        return optionsValue.map((optionValue, i) =>
            <option value={optionValue.value} key={i}>{optionValue.name}</option>
        );
    };
```